# automate brew upgrade when there is a conflict

Tags: homebrew

When there is a conflict, `brew upgrade` will stop. For this particular case, I will use `parallel` from the gnu `parallel` package instead of from `moreutils`. When I originally installed them, I installed `moreutils` first then force install `parallel`. Can upgrade for this case be automated? I don't want to always do this manually.

```
==> Upgrading parallel 
Error: Cannot install parallel because conflicting formulae are installed.
  moreutils: because both install a `parallel` executable.

Please `brew unlink moreutils` before continuing.

Unlinking removes a formula's symlinks from /usr/local. You can
link the formula again after the install finishes. You can --force this
install, but the build may fail or cause obscure side effects in the
resulting software.
```

Comment: You may want to view this question on https://superuser.com/q/545889